# Very very simple Rich Text / WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: richtextbox, wysiwyg, jwysiwyg

Im looking for a very very simple editor for my forum.

Im only interested in basic functions such as bold, italic, underline, blockquote - nothing more, nothing less.
Another important feature is when the user is pasting formatted text into the textarea all tags should be stripped.

Im familiar with TinyMCE, CKEditor and a some of the other "big" editors, but I think its overkill to implement such a big "framework" for such basic functions..

Ive looked through the "Similar questions" but none of the suggested editors are simple enough i think..

Do you guys know any?

Answer (score 0):

> It is difficult to define the "simplicity".

There are many [rich text editors](http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/rich-text-editor) which give the facility of what buttons you want to display in the toolbar.

Have a look on [this](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/refs/contentEditableEX2.htm) smallest test editor example with basic features: bold, italic, and underline via hot keys.

Or check another example of [execCommands](http://codepen.io/netsi1964/pen/QbLLGW) that you can use to make your **own** simplified minified text editor. You can control the design of buttons toolbar etc. It has list of commands and this very small code to turn them into rich text editor.

```
angular.module("myApp", [])
    .directive("click", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.bind("click", function () {
                    scope.$evalAsync(attrs.click);
                });
            }
        };
    })
    .controller("Example", function ($scope) {
        $scope.supported = function (cmd) {
            var css = !!document.queryCommandSupported(cmd.cmd) ? "btn-succes" : "btn-error"
            return css
        };
        $scope.icon = function (cmd) {
            return (typeof cmd.icon !== "undefined") ? "fa fa-" + cmd.icon : "";
        };
        $scope.doCommand = function (cmd) {
            if ($scope.supported(cmd) === "btn-error") {
                alert("execCommand(“" + cmd.cmd + "”)\nis not supported in your browser");
                return;
            }
            val = (typeof cmd.val !== "undefined") ? prompt("Value for " + cmd.cmd + "?", cmd.val) : "";
            document.execCommand(cmd.cmd, false, (cmd.val || ""));
        }
        $scope.commands = commands;
        $scope.tags = [
    'Bootstrap', 'AngularJS', 'execCommand'
  ]
    })
```